# TFIDF Vectorizer throws ValueError: empty vocabulary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

So I'm trying to use the sklearn TFIDF Vectorizer on some text data and I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

Here's the code:

```
tf_idf_vect = tfi(stop_words = 'english',
                 max_features = 20)

x = data['text']

#data = [tweets.strip() for tweets in x]
#texts = [[word.lower() for word in tweet.split()]]
         
tf_idf = tf_idf_vect.fit_transform([' '.join(tweet) for tweet in x]) # This line is causing the error
tf_idf_norm = normalize(tf_idf)
tf_idf_array = tf_idf_norm.toarray()

vector = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_array,
                     columns = tf_idf_vect.get_feature_names())
vector.head()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over your data.
Try this:

```
 x = ["text"]

tf_idf = tf_idf_vect.fit_transform(x)
tf_idf_norm = normalize(tf_idf)
tf_idf_array = tf_idf_norm.toarray()

vector = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_array,
                      columns=tf_idf_vect.get_feature_names())
print(f"head: {vector.head()}")
```

And gave me this output:
head:    text
0   1.0